# apache alternate port and mod_dir trailing slash with port rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have Apache listening on an alternate port (8000) behind a proxy on the same system (node.js), which is listening on port 80. All works well, except that mod_dir in Apache will rewrite trailing slashes by default, and is appending the port in the location header.

In other words, I am able to load the Apache web page just fine, but when I click a link in the page that points to a directory, I get a 301 from Apache, with the location header like so:

Location: www.example.com:8000/_my_path/

Apache is just innocently handing out the port, because it doesn't know any better, but I need it to stop added the port.  mod_rewrite seems to be the correct approach, but I am not sure about the following:

1. Which triggers first, mod_rewrite or mod_dir?
2. Do I need to disable mod_dir and then try to compensate for all of it's behavior with mod_rewrite?
3. Is there a better way that I missed?

Server version: Apache/2.2.22 (Debian)

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following to my  directive resolved the issue:

RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond $1 !/$
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/ -d
 RewriteRule (.+) http://www.example.com/$1/ [R=301,L]

I would post the links where I gleaned this information from, but apparently I don't have enough "reputation"... :/